# c3po configuration and mysql aborted connections

Tags: java, mysql, c3p0

I got a lot of `Aborted connection` messages on DB side -  `[Note] Aborted connection 11043 to db: 'mysql' user: 'mysql' host: Got an error reading communication packets`.

I have no problem with the application and the DB, but I wonder why I getting these messages.

Could it be because `hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_periods` is higher than `hibernate.c3p0.timeout` ?

Here is the hibernate configuration file:

```
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.max_fetch_depth=3
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=com.p.db.pMySqlDialect
hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=10
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=0
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=0
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=3
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=400
hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery=select 1
hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=5
hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay=1000
hibernate.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure=false
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin=false
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=false
```

DB access log:

```
DEBUG [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsx9l7vpkfr1egte0l|cf2bf60]-HelperThread-#2] [UID:, MSG_ID:] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] <Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@41d8a248] on IDLE CHECK has SUCCEEDED.>
DEBUG [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsx9l7vpkfr1egte0l|cf2bf60]-HelperThread-#1] [UID:, MSG_ID:] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] <Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@7d10203] on IDLE CHECK.>
DEBUG [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsx9l7vpkfr1egte0l|cf2bf60]-HelperThread-#0] [UID:, MSG_ID:] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] <Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@264d3257] on IDLE CHECK.>
DEBUG [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsx9l7vpkfr1egte0l|cf2bf60]-HelperThread-#2] [UID:, MSG_ID:] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] <Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@ea7e8fb] on IDLE CHECK.>
DEBUG [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsx9l7vpkfr1egte0l|cf2bf60]-HelperThread-#0] [UID:, MSG_ID:] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] <Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@264d3257] on IDLE CHECK has SUCCEEDED.>
DEBUG [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsx9l7vpkfr1egte0l|cf2bf60]-HelperThread-#1] [UID:, MSG_ID:] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] <Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@7d10203] on IDLE CHECK has SUCCEEDED.>
DEBUG [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsx9l7vpkfr1egte0l|cf2bf60]-HelperThread-#0] [UID:, MSG_ID:] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] <Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@2cb753e7] on IDLE CHECK.>
DEBUG [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsx9l7vpkfr1egte0l|cf2bf60]-HelperThread-#2] [UID:, MSG_ID:] [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool] <Test of PooledConnection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connections eventually go stale. Please configure some Connection testing. The simplest thing to do would be to just modify your config so that

```
hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
```

Or, see [c3p0 docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing).

Comment: thanks, but I am not sure how it related to my issue? adding `testConnectionOnCheckout=true` gives performance penalty ?

Comment: Your application seeing stale Connections—Connections that are no longer valid + generate errors when they try to communicate with the RDBMS. If you configure c3p0 to test Connection, the pool will detect these stale Connections + eliminate them before your application ever sees them. `testConnectionOnCheckout=true` does impose a performance cost, but as long as you are using a recent JDBC driver, the cost will be modest [it will use the fast Connection.isValid() method]. If the cost of test on checkout is unacceptable, you can use test on checkin and idle tests. But you probably don't need to

Comment: what do you mean with "you can use test on checkin and idle tests"?

Comment: See Step 3 the green box in the docs (linked in the answer above). But as long as you are using a recent JDBC driver and the most recent c3p0 (0.9.5.2), it probably isn't worth the trouble, testConnectionOnCheckout=true will probably be fine.